Maximum principle for heat equation at $t=0$
After explaining the maximum principle for the heat equation with $u=0$ boundary conditions, a remark was made that a similar argument could be made for:
\begin{align}
u_{t}&=\Delta u& &\text{on } U \times(0, T)\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}& =0 & &\text{on }\partial U\\
u(x,0)&=u_0 .
\end{align}
Specifically, that for a smooth $\partial U$, $u$ achieves its maximum and minimum values at $t=0$. Trying to see the details of this, I first applied the maximum principle by assuming there was a local maximum at a point $(x_0,t_0)=p_0 \in U$ such that
\begin{equation} u_t - \Delta u <0.\end{equation}
For $t_0 >0$, this would mean
\begin{align}
u_t(p_0) &= 0 \\
\nabla u(p_0) &= 0 \\
\Delta u(p_0) &\le 0 \\
\end{align}
and at final time
\begin{align}
u_t(p_0) &\ge 0 \\
\nabla u(p_0) &= 0 \\
\Delta u(p_0) &\le 0 
\end{align}
In both cases, the signs of $u_t$ and $\Delta u$ contradict the inequality given by the assumption. So, the maximum must be at $t=0$ or on $\partial  U$.
To show that it's at $t=0$, I think we'll just need to rule out it being on the boundary so we can apply the boundary condition. So,
\begin{equation} u^{\epsilon, \delta}=u-\delta \phi(x)-\epsilon t
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{align}
(u^{\epsilon, \delta})_t &= \Delta u^{\epsilon, \delta}\\
u_t-\epsilon &= \Delta u - \delta \Delta \phi(x)
\end{align}
Questions:

How do we conclude that the maximum (minimum) are at $t=0$ from here? Is it to apply the maximum principle again such that $u_t - \Delta u + \delta \Delta \phi(x) -\epsilon <0$? If so, how does that work?
$u^{\epsilon, \delta}$ was recommended, but how could I have constructed that on my own versus something like $u^{\epsilon}=u(x) + \epsilon t$?

